# Python 3.3 - Formatting Issue

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a 2 programs that I've created. The first one writes a text file named `celeb.txt` file with a list of celebrity names that the user inputs. My second code reads that list and displays it.

The code works for both programs but I can not seem to get my formatting correct. I was the names to be listed vertical and not in a straight line. I don't want to combine the codes into 1 program either.

Ok so here is the first code that gets the user to end the names of celebrities:

```
import sys

def main():
myfile = open('celeb.txt', 'w')
celeb = input('Enter celebrity name or Enter to quit ')
if celeb:
    myfile.write(str(celeb)+ '\n')

else:
    sys.exit(0)

myfile.close()
print('File was created and closed')

main()
```

Here is my code that reads that .txt and outputs the names. I can't figure out how to list the name 1 on top of the other and not on 1 straight line.

```
def main():
myfile = open('celeb.txt', 'r')

line1 = myfile.readline()

myfile.close()

print(line1)

main()
```

Comment: You have not written the names correctly, you should be adding a newline after each name when you write, if readline shows all the names then you wrote them all on a single line. What does 'celeb.txt' look like?

Comment: My celeb.txt program looks like this:                                                import sys

def main():
    myfile = open('celeb.txt', 'w')
    celeb = input('Enter celebrity name or Enter to quit ')
    if celeb:
        myfile.write(str(celeb)+ '\n')

    else:
        sys.exit(0)

    myfile.close()
    print('File was created and closed')

main()

Comment: I meant  the contents, add what the content looks likes to your question, it looks like you are adding a newline but that does not seem to add up with getting all the names with readline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take multiple names either take a name at a time:

```
def get_names(fle):
    with open(fle,"a") as f:   
        while True:
            inp = input("Enter a name or 'q' to quit :")
            if inp == "q":
                return 
            f.write("{}\n".format(inp))

def read_names(fle):
    # open names file 
    with open(fle) as f:
        # iterate over the file 
        # printing a name/line at a time
        for name in f:
            print(name)
```

Or if you are taking multiple names in one line get the user to separate the names and split before writing:

```
def get_names(fle):
    with open(fle,"a") as f:
        inp = input("Enter names separated by a space :")
        f.writelines(("{}\n".format(n) for n in inp.split()))

def read_names(fle):
    with open(fle) as f:
        for name in f:
            print(name)
```